# How can I pay for flight school in the UK?

Tags: flight-training, cost

I want to apply for the British Airways future pilot programme. However, it costs £125,000. The biggest loan I can get is £20,000 so where am I supposed to get the rest of that money?

I've heard people telling me that you can get a sponsorship, but I've looked online and cannot find any sponsorship deals because it's all self funded.

Comment: What level of training / certification do you have so far?  Its one thing for someone with no flight experience at all the aim for B.A.   Its quite different for someone with a PPL / IFR rating to decide they want to aim for an ATP rating.

Comment: I have a couple of hours in the 172 but no license

Comment: Before you look at a massive loan to become a commercial pilot, perhaps you should make some small steps by getting initial ratings at a more reasonable cost?  Once you have demonstrated exceptional skills at a lower level, you will be more likely to find resources to move up to the next level.  Right now, you're trying to run a marathon, but have never jogged around the block before.

Answer (score 4):

There are specialist firms providing loans for aviation training, however it is unlikely that you will be able to get a loan of the amount you would need for an integrated course without some form of security.

The security usually takes one of two forms.  The first is a charge on a property (belonging to you or your parents).  The other is an airline agreeing to act as a guarantor/sponsor, however this doesn't appear to apply in this case as this particular scheme states it is fully self-funded.

If you cannot raise the financing for this particular scheme, you can apply to other schemes that provide some sponsorship or underwrite the loan as they become available.  Naturally there tends to be more competition for these schemes.  Some are targeted towards under-represented potential pilots, such as the Amy Johnson initiative by Easyjet, where they will guarantee/underwrite the loan for a limited number of female trainees.

It is also possible to undertake modular training, where the cost can be closer to £50,000.  There are a number of organisations that can provide funding towards some of the costs, particularly for young pilots.  These include The Honourable Company of Air Pilots, The Air League and The Royal Aeroclub Trust.

Before spending significant sums on training, it is advisable to get a class one medical, to avoid possible disappointment after spending significant sums of money that cannot be recovered.

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply